# PHP Clickable Row that display data of details?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How can I do clickable tab that display data?

I want to fetch the data from mysql row to the row in the table dynamically and when i open her i will see the details of all the the row in my database. Like in this picture.

https://ibb.co/m0Zmk7

Comment: Your URL links to a 404 page.

Comment: URL Not working also please share us your code

Comment: I saw that https://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid21.php but something goes wrong in the code and i can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get your question wrong, you want to display some data from database when user will click on a row.

You need to call a function on every row just like this:

```
<tr onclick="somefunction(id)"></tr> OR <div onclick="somefunction(id)"></div>
```

Also you have to create a div where your data will be populated.

```
<div id="display_data"></div>
```

And then JS function would be just like:

```
<script>
function somefunction(id){
    $('#display_data').remove();        //it will remove all the data before loading new record.

            $.ajax({
            url: "pathOfYourFile/function/",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {

                if(data.status==1){
                    alert("success");
                    $('#display_data').show();
                    $('#display_data').append(data.message);
                }else{
                    alert(record error);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {

                console.log(data);

            }
        });
}
<script>
```

And in the end you have to write a function in php that will get your data from database. Just make sure that you will return data just like this:

```
$data['json_data'] = array('status' => 1,                                               
                            'message' => $record
                           );
```

I Hope this will work in your case. Please do not hesitate to ask a question if there is any confusion.